# Maximum Likelihood Estimation Identity question

Tags: arithmetic

Is summation of logarithm of a random variable equal to the logarithm of the sum of the random variable.

Comment: Have you contemplated some particular examples?  For instance, is it the case that $\log(1)+\log(1)=\log(2)$?

Answer (score 3):

In general $\sum \ln{x_i} \neq \ln{\sum x_i}$ The sum of logs IS equal to the log of the PRODUCTs, which is just a consequence of the definition of a logarithm.